# why Python3 str(bytes) converts to literal string b'<str>'

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-3.6, python-unicode

I am using python3. Following is example which explains question.

```
# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Sep 26 2019, 11:57:09) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> help(str)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
 |  
 |  Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
 |  errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
 |  that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
 |  Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
 |  or repr(object).
 |  encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
 |  errors defaults to 'strict'.

>>> d = b'abcd'
>>> type(d)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(d)
b'abcd'
>>> len(d)
4
>>> m = str(d)
>>> type(m)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(m)
b'abcd'
>>> len(m)
7
>>> m.encode()
b"b'abcd'"
>>> 
>>> m = str(d, encoding='utf-8')
>>> type(m)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(m)
abcd
>>> len(m)
4
>>>
```

It is mentioned in help(str) "encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding()" still str(d) converts string with b'' in it. Note the len of string is 7 now. Question is,

1. why default coding needs to be specified explicitly to make correct string out of bytes
2. How to get back to bytes - New type is string. (encode on string will add that extra b)
3. is there way that pylint catch/warn this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`str()` for `bytes` is the same as the `repr()` is for `bytes`, exactly for the reason that you wouldn't end up misusing it. Here's a more complex example, where the source string is an emoji.

```
>>> s = ""
>>> len(s)
1  # One codepoint.
>>> b = s.encode("utf-8")
>>> len(b)
4  # Four bytes.
>>> print(b)
b'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb8'  # Repr of the bytes, not to be interpreted.
>>> print(repr(b))
b'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb8'  # Same as above!
>>> s2 = b.decode("utf-8")  # Decode back to string from bytes.
>>> s == s2
True
>>>
```

That is, use `str.encode()` to get bytes from a string, `bytes.decode()` to get a string from bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `str` not as a casting function (as in C and C++), but as a string representation (to be print, so it could be different to `repr()`) of the value.

The problem is that there is not good printable string of a binary array, so I assume there is not specific `str()` function, so it fall back to `repr()`, which add some extra annotation (for developer), like the prefix `b'`.

Python cannot convert binary data to a string, without knowing the encoding. (binary is *coded*: `a` is `0x61` in ASCII, and string is *decoded*: `a` means `a`).

So you may want to `d.decode('utf-8')`.

Note: system encoding is a different thing. It is used for terminal input and output, but not for binary array, or in general data read from disk.

Answer (score 1):

> If encoding [..] is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer that will be decoded using the given encoding [..]. Otherwise, returns the result of `object.__str__()` (if defined) or `repr(object)`.

This pretty much answers your questions. If you omit the `encoding` argument, then `repr(object)` is used, which results in `"b'...'"` as the resulting string value. If you do supply the `encoding` argument, then it will attempt to decode the supplied object with that encoding. Those are two fundamentally different operations:

1. Produce a string representation of the object, which is pretty safe and can't really fail.
2. Decode a binary object, i.e. try to interpret its contents in some way, which may very well fail.

Those two operations are represented by two different ways to call the `str` function. You would not want to implicitly trigger variation #2 and have potential error conditions to deal with by some implicitly set global value, when all you expected was to do #1.

Answer (score 1):

> is there way that pylint catch/warn this problem

I don't think pylint would catch it, but mypy would, if you are willing to add type annotations to your code.

Python will issue a warning when `str` is called on a `bytes` instance if it is executed with the [`-b`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-b) flag.

```sh
$ python3 -b -c 'str(b"a")'
-c:1: BytesWarning: str() on a bytes instance
```

Note that the warning is only raised once, AFAICT.

If executed with `-bb`, an exception will be raised.

```sh
python3 -bb -c 'str(b"a")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
BytesWarning: str() on a bytes instance
```